# Foundation 6 - Top-Bar | How can I keep the logo on smaller devices?

Tags: html, css, navigation, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I try to create  a responsive top-bar with logo, left menu and right menu. On mobile devices I want the horizontal menu to become a vertical menu under a "hamburger icon".

I want the logo to remain always visible. For mobile devices to the left of the hamburger icon. Also add icons.

I checked the example from Zurb, but I don't want the logo/site-title to go inside the hamburger menu on smaller screen.

```html
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
</div>
<div class="top-bar">
    <li><img src="" > </li>
<div  id="main-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">

    <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
            <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu">
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve the following result (it was done with bootstrap)

[image]
[image]

Comment: This should be a good starting point for you:
http://zurb.com/building-blocks/f6-top-bar

Comment: I checked the examples from Zurb and other sites before asking. In the example the "Site Title" from the left, on smaller screens goes under the hamburger menu, I don't want that to happen - this is what I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the image in the small screen different in this case (smaller if needed). The Foundation 6 docs are not that great yet so here is a pretty good implementation of your code. Be sure to include the background-color of your bar. Not much extra css necessary.

```
    <div class="title-bar" style="width:100%;background-color: #262626;">
        <div class="title-bar-left hide-for-medium">
            <span class="title-bar-title"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x40?text=Viberr" ></span>
            <button data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" class="menu-icon" type="button" ></button>
        </div>

        <div id="responsive-menu" >
            <div class="top-bar-title">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/80x40?text=Viberr" >
            </div>

            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                    <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="top-bar-right">
                <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: On the normal header the logo appears on the left, on smaller screen sizes the logo appears inside the hamburger menu.

The solution you proposed adds a new logo in front of the hamburger menu, but it doesn't remove the initial/logo from dropdown.

What I want is the initial logo to remain on the same position indifferent of the screen size; if I move the logo in another div above(outside) the top-bar div, will break the design

Comment: @user3541631, edited the code a bit to show how to add the image in both med/large and smaller sizes and allow for a different version of the same image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a little CSS for this. I have modified the default top bar example.

HTML

```
<div class="top-bar stacked-for-small">
  <div class="top-bar-title">
    <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    </span>
    <strong>Site Title</strong>
  </div>
  <div id="responsive-menu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu>li {
    display: block;
}
.top-bar input {
    float:left;
}
.top-bar-title{
  float:none;
}
.top-bar-title span{
  float:right;
}
@media (min-width:640px){
  .menu>li {
      display: table-cell;
  }
  .top-bar-title{
    float: left;
  }
}
```

See the CodePen Example. http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/wGORZY